# upload and diplay big CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I have a script that uploads and display a CSV file into HTML table.
My problem is that I have an error when I try to open big files.
My file is about 4.5 Mo with 80000 lines. It works fine with small files but I get

> Warning: fopen(upload/test.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/cvs/PHP charts/sb-admin-v2/test.php on line 45

with big files
Here is my code

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
<?php
//upload
// for set memory limit & execution time
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '180');
if ( isset($_POST["submit"]) ) {

   if ( isset($_FILES["file"])) {

            //if there was an error uploading the file
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";

        }
        else {

                 //if file already exists
             if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
             }
             else {
                    //Store file in directory "upload" with the name of "uploaded_file.txt"
            $storagename = "test.csv";
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $storagename);
            echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
            }
        }
     } else {
             echo "No file selected <br />";
     }
}


//display
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("upload/test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

    echo '<table border="1">';

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        if ($row == 1) {
            echo '<thead><tr>';
        }else{
            echo '<tr>';
        }

        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            //echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            if(empty($data[$c])) {
               $value = "&nbsp;";
            }else{
               $value = $data[$c];
            }
            if ($row == 1) {
                echo '<th>'.$value.'</th>';
            }else{
                echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
            }
        }

        if ($row == 1) {
            echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';
        }else{
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        $row++;
    }

    echo '</tbody></table>';
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: have you checked if the file already exists there?

Comment: *"My file is about 4.5 Mo"* - I'd say try and increase your memory size and execution time.

Comment: I did it, I delete the file from the upload/ dir, same problem.

Comment: @Fred-ii- , I did it . I added ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '180'); same problem

Comment: Look at the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php - It states **length** *"Must be greater than the longest line (in characters) to be found in the CSV file (allowing for trailing line-end characters). It became optional in PHP 5. Omitting this parameter (or setting it to 0 in PHP 5.1.0 and later) the maximum line length is not limited, which is slightly slower."*

Comment: @Fred-ii-, you didnt get my probem, When I try with a file of some lines, it works, when I try with bigger file, it doesnt. all lines hav same lenght

Comment: Check to see if your temp folder isn't full. Also try increasing the values you already set for memory limit and execution time. Something is failing somewhere. Check your logs and add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Maybe even a `try{...} catch{...}` method.

Comment: You may be exceeding PHP's max upload file size. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Comment: @Fred-ii- Why would a memory or execution time limit cause a `File not found` error?

Comment: @Barmar, Thx that's was my problem. I figured it out when I copy manually the file into the upload dir, so the problem was in the upload function. thank you

Comment: @Barmar You have a point there. Your comment makes more sense. I knew I was missing something. I thought it might have been a tmp file size also, filling up the temp folder; it's happened to me before.

Answer (score 0):

Well when I ran into this problem I resorted to a client side solution with https://github.com/knrz/CSV.js. Works very well and takes the load off my server. Only thing is I did not need the entire CSV to be uploaded to my server, once parsed only selective portions were sent using ajax.

If you are only trying to display the data in HTML table this can be a very good solution.